# Как вывести данные из базы Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

В ячейке **xfields** написано несколько ссылок таким образом.
`audio|vip.mp3||image|vip.jpg||wave|19.jpg`

Если я вывожу так `".$row['xfields']."` выводится полностью вся ячейка.

Как вывести только картинку `vip.jpg`

Полный код

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_post ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {

$row['date'] = strtotime($row['date']);

if ($config['allow_alt_url'] == "yes")
$rat .= "<div class=\"rate\"><a {$go_page}href=\"".$config['http_home_url'].date('Y/m/d/', $row['date']).$row['alt_name'].".html\">".$row['tags']." - ".$row['title']."</a></div>";
else
$rat .= "<div class=\"rate\"><a {$go_page}href=\"".$config['http_home_url'].date('Y/m/d/', $row['date']).$row['alt_name'].".html\">".$row['tags']." - ".$row['title']."</a></div>";
```

После `$rat .= "` нужно вывести

Comment: `echo explode('|', $row['xfields'])[4];`.......но лучше так не хранить, имхо

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку. Вставить нужно после  `$rat .= "`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
//метод один
$str = 'audio|vip.mp3||image|vip.jpg||wave|19.jpg';
preg_match('#image\|([^|]+\.(?:gif|jpe?g))\|#isU', $str, $matches);
if (isset($matches[1])) {
    echo $matches[1];
}


//метод два
$str = 'audio|vip.mp3||image|vip.jpg||wave|19.jpg';
$list = explode('||', $str);
foreach ($list as $val) {
    $arr[explode('|', $val)[0]] = explode('|', $val)[1];
}

if (isset($arr['image'])) {
    echo $arr['image'];
}
```

Comment: И как это использовать? Мне же не одну картинку нужно вывести. У них названия разные.

Comment: @steep ну так больше инфы надо в вопросе подкидывать.